# Succulent turning yellow

Tags: diagnosis, succulents, cactus

My plant is suddenly turning yellow and I don't know what it wrong with it or if it is normal. I have it for about 4 month and this happened only this week. I don't know if it's related, but it has been very hot in my country these days.

[image]

[image]

This is a photo from a few days ago when I asked about the identification of the plant. (Euphorbia mammillaris)
[image]

edit: The yellow parts dried and I'm worried for the others. I didn't water it at all since then and I added some sand. Should I cut the dead parts? Do you think the rest of the plant is affected?

[image]

Comment: Is this by any chance the part of the plant that faces the sun or is closest to the heat? Has anything else in the environment changed? (new curtains, blinds have been up, etc). The yellowed parts look a little "deflated", which can be caused by too much sun. If so, turn the plant so a different side is toward the sun. If it doesn't get worse (if it's not continually exposed to too my radiation) it should heal, though I'm not super familiar with that plant.

Comment: Yes, that part was near the window. Now I moved it and I'll try to see what happens in the next days.

Answer (score 4):

If it has been very hot, did you water more than usual? This looks like water damage(overwatering)[image: leaf]

Comment: I didn't water it more. But I will try to replant it.